# Sentence Analysis: "We never let you stand in the rain."

Tags: word-usage

> **We never let you stand in the rain.**

What do you think about this sentence? Is the sentence wrong? What improvements could be made?

In my opinion future should be used:

> We will never let you stand in the rain.

Moreover the correct expression is *to be left out in the rain* or *to sell someone down the river*, so

> We will you never leave you out in the rain.

Anyway, I won't be able to decide, if the first sentence is just suboptimal or wrong?

Comment: Unless we know the idea you want to convey, there's no use in trying to improve the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"We will never let you stand in the rain" is not a metaphorical sentence.  It literally means, "We will not permit you to stand in the rain".

If instead you mean this to be a kind of advertising slogan, to suggest the company will never *abandon* you, then the correct idiom is "leave you standing in the rain"

> We will never **leave you standing** in the rain.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence ("we never...") is past tense. It says that we (whoever "we" are) have protected you (whoever the "you" is) in the past because we didn't let you do something foolish like stand in the rain. You might say this to someone if you want to argue that since you have acted in their interests in the past you are likely still acting in their interest when you tell them to do something they don't immediately want to (or not do something they do want to).

Your proposed replacements are all in future tense, implying a promise to do something in the future.

So both sentences are grammatical, but the meanings are completely different.

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that the first sentence is past tense; it could just as easily be present habitual to express something that is generally true. And the difference between present habitual and future is much murkier.